# Firefox : How to reset the new tab's tiles

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, thumbnails

I am using Firefox 34 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when I press open a new tab it shows the most visited sites in a  "tiles" format. Unfortunately for some reason the thumbnails of the tiles don't show anything.They are just blank.Is there a way to reset this and make it save the thumbnails again?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way to reset this and make it save the thumbnails again?

I would say: yes there is.
In my case the tiles weren't white but they had coockie-flags on the that seemed to stay there forever.

This is what I finally found out:
- in the address bar of firefox put: about:cache and hit enter.
In the screen that opens you can see where your system leaves the browsercache of firefox.
Then you close firefox and with a filemanager browse to the mozilla-cache and delete it. You will loose no passwords and so. It is harmless.
Then restart firefox.
This is the way to force firefox to refresh the tiles on the newtab page.

Comment: You can clear the cache from Firefox: `Edit>Preferences>Advanced>Network`.

Answer (score -3):

You can enable the title feature by clicking the "settings" icon located on the top right most corner of the web-page.[image]